# Are any of the Upapuranas translated into English or published in Sanskrit?

Tags: puranas, translation, upapuranas

I know that the 18 Mahapuranas are translated into English. But, Is any Upa Purana translated in English or published in Sanskrit?

Comment: All available Upapauranas have been published atleast in their Sanskrit originals in some part of India. Gitapress published the Nrisimha Purana with its Hindi translation. Vishwanarayana Shastri had translated the Kalikapurana in English. An English translation of the Devi Bhagavatam is available.